# Deploying spring-boot Backbone application into Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, backbone.js, cloud, cloud-foundry

My application is on spring-boot and Backbone.js based. Can I deploy this application to Pivotal Cloud Foundry? If yes, How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack to package your application.

This link will give you an idea. 
https://keyholesoftware.com/2015/11/16/backbonejs-with-webpack-a-lesson-in-optimization/

If you want a good example, look at [willitconnect](https://github.com/krujos/willitconnect). It doesn't use Backbone, but you will get the idea.

Here's another example - http://justincalleja.com/2016/04/17/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/

Give it a try.

Comment: From a CloudFoundry standpoint, the answer is yes.  Simply `cf push` your application, like any other application.  The Java buildpack will run since you have a Java & Spring Boot based application.  The fact you're using Backbone.js or any other client-side Javascript library is irrelevant to Cloud Foundry.  You just need to configure your Spring Boot app to serve up the Javascript files.  You can do that in a number of ways, see suggestions above.